# Как передать индекс объекта из массива родительского стейта, в дочерний компонент React js

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

В стейте родителя есть массив, который состоит из объектов. В дочернем рендерится таблица в которой отображаются свойства объектов. Напротив каждой строки есть кнопка delete и нужно реализовать удаление выбранного объекта. Реализована функция удаления в родительском компоненте:

```
  deleteUser = (i) =>{
        let arr = this.state.info
          arr.splice(i,1)
          this.setState({info: arr})

    }
```

Она прокидывается в дочерний и вызывается из кнопки. Вопрос: как получить индекс объекта и использовать его в функции.

Comment: индекс прокидывается же в дочернкий компонент? та вызывайте обработчик  не на прямую, а через метод дочернего компонента, где через `props` можно получить индекс

Answer (score 0):

примерно так

```js
const Table = props => {
  const {data, deleteHandler} = props;

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map(item => {
          return (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{item.id}</td>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td onClick={(event) => deleteHandler(event, item.id)}>X</td>
            </tr>
          )
        }}
      </tbody
    </table>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {id: 1, name: 'A'},
      {id: 2, name: 'B'},
      {id: 3, name: 'C'},
    ]
  }
  
  deleteHandler = (event, id) => {
    this.setState(({data}) => {
      return {
        data: data.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      }
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return <Table data={this.state.data} deleteHandler={this.deleteHandler}/>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById(root));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```